# Where does the extra ‘aus’ come from?

Tags: sentence-structure, usage

From dw:

> Millionen Menschen in Deutschland arbeiten in der Corona-Pandemie von zu Hause aus.

Why is there an ‘aus’ in the end? It doesn’t seem to come from ‘ausarbeiten’.

Comment: @David Vogt: Though DWDS does list *a* meaning of *von ... aus* under *von*, it's not clear that's what it means here. The meaning in the other question seems to be referring to the one in DWDS. In English you can say "I can see the lake *from out* of my window," or "I'm running a business *from out* of my house," same expression but different meanings, and perhaps that's what's going on here. Wiktionary has an entry for *von ... aus*, but the definition given is rather vague.

Comment: *"It doesn’t seem to come from ‘auskommen’."* - I'm a bit confused about this statement, since there is no *"kommen"* or *"auskommen"* in the example sentence. Why would you expect *aus* to be derived from *auskommen* then?

Comment: @David Vogt: I am still confused. "Von...aus" makes sentence in the other question, but here people work "from home"; "Von...aus"' sounds to me like "from home out/from out of home"....

Comment: @Arsak: sorry I meant "ausarbeiten", which doesn't really fit in here. I edited the question.